# how to install nf_conntrack module in RHEL

Tags: ipv6

I tried installing nf_conntrack module in RHEL , it fails

[root@boot]# modprobe nf_conntrack_ipv6

FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_ipv6 not found.

[root@boot]# modprobe nf_conntrack

FATAL: Module nf_conntrack not found.

[root@boot]# lsmod | grep -i nf

nfnetlink_queue        16129  2

nfnetlink              10713  4 nfnetlink_queue,ip_conntrack

xt_NFQUEUE              6209  2

x_tables               17349  18 xt_tcpudp,xt_state,ipt_addrtype,ipt_TOS,ipt_tos
,xt_string,ipt_owner,xt_multiport,xt_MARK,xt_mark,ipt_iprange,ipt_hashlimit,xt_c
onntrack,xt_CONNMARK,xt_connmark,ip_tables,xt_NFQUEUE,ip6_tables

[root@boot]# 
[root@boot]# 
[root@boot]# lsmod | grep -i nf

nfnetlink_queue        16129  2

nfnetlink              10713  4 nfnetlink_queue,ip_conntrack

xt_NFQUEUE              6209  2

x_tables               17349  18 xt_tcpudp,xt_state,ipt_addrtype,ipt_TOS,ipt_tos
,xt_string,ipt_owner,xt_multiport,xt_MARK,xt_mark,ipt_iprange,ipt_hashlimit,xt_c
onntrack,xt_CONNMARK,xt_connmark,ip_tables,xt_NFQUEUE,ip6_tables

[root@boot]# 
[root@boot]# lsmod | grep -i conntrack

xt_conntrack            6593  0

ip_conntrack           53281  4 xt_state,xt_conntrack,xt_CONNMARK,xt_connmark

nfnetlink              10713  4 nfnetlink_queue,ip_conntrack

x_tables               17349  18 xt_tcpudp,xt_state,ipt_addrtype,ipt_TOS,ipt_tos
,xt_string,ipt_owner,xt_multiport,xt_MARK,xt_mark,ipt_iprange,ipt_hashlimit,xt_c
onntrack,xt_CONNMARK,xt_connmark,ip_tables,xt_NFQUEUE,ip6_tables
[root@boot]#

[root@boot]# cat  config-2.6.18-194.el5PAE  | grep -i "nf_"

CONFIG_IP_NF_CONNTRACK=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_CT_ACCT=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_CONNTRACK_MARK=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_CONNTRACK_SECMARK=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_CONNTRACK_NETLINK=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_CT_PROTO_SCTP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_FTP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_IRC=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NETBIOS_NS=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TFTP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_AMANDA=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_PPTP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_H323=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_SIP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_QUEUE=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_IPRANGE=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TOS=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_RECENT=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ECN=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_DSCP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_AH=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_TTL=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_OWNER=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_ADDRTYPE=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_HASHLIMIT=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REJECT=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_LOG=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ULOG=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TCPMSS=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_NEEDED=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_NETMAP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_SAME=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_SNMP_BASIC=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_IRC=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_FTP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_TFTP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_AMANDA=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_PPTP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_H323=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT_SIP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_MANGLE=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TOS=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_ECN=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_DSCP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_TTL=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_CLUSTERIP=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_RAW=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPTABLES=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARPFILTER=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_ARP_MANGLE=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_QUEUE=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_IPTABLES=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_RT=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_OPTS=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_FRAG=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_HL=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_OWNER=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_IPV6HEADER=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_AH=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MATCH_EUI64=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_FILTER=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_LOG=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_REJECT=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_MANGLE=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_TARGET_HL=m
CONFIG_IP6_NF_RAW=m
CONFIG_BRIDGE_NF_EBTABLES=m
[root@boot]#

[root@boot]# uname -a

Linux 2.6.18-194.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Mar 16 22:00:21 EDT 2010 i686 i686
 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@boot]#

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is to compile the ipv6 conntrack modules yourself, since they aren't included in the standard RHEL 5 kernels.  Your other choice is to leave the firewall pretty wide open so that you can get the IPv6 traffic out which is probably a bad idea but may be acceptable in certain circumstances.

Another workaround would be to use a local web proxy so that at least your web traffic can go out over IPv6.  The trouble then is finding one which supports IPv6 well.